# Why are custom error messages not used for Mage_Core_Exception

Tags: exception

Referring to the example code below, in the case of `Mage_Core_Exception` why is the error message from the exception being used directly `$e->getMessage()` rather than a custom message like  `$result['error_msg'] = $this->__('There was an error processing ...')`

Doesn't this represent a security risk where the error message from the exception might be something like "unknown table user_password in the database" and this gets sent to the frontend via AJAX or other means?

Path: app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php

```
public function responseAction()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    /* @var $paymentMethod Mage_Authorizenet_Model_DirectPost */
    $paymentMethod = Mage::getModel('authorizenet/directpost');

    $result = array();
    if (!empty($data['x_invoice_num'])) {
        $result['x_invoice_num'] = $data['x_invoice_num'];
    }

    try {
        if (!empty($data['store_id'])) {
            $paymentMethod->setStore($data['store_id']);
        }
        $paymentMethod->process($data);
        $result['success'] = 1;
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $result['success'] = 0;
        $result['error_msg'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $result['success'] = 0;
        $result['error_msg'] = $this->__('There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.');
    }

    if (!empty($data['controller_action_name'])) {
        if (!empty($data['key'])) {
            $result['key'] = $data['key'];
        }
        $result['controller_action_name'] = $data['controller_action_name'];
        $result['is_secure'] = isset($data['is_secure']) ? $data['is_secure'] : false;
        $params['redirect'] = Mage::helper('authorizenet')->getRedirectIframeUrl($result);
    }
    $block = $this->_getIframeBlock()->setParams($params);
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a `Mage_Core_Exception` exception thrown without knowing the exception message.

Here are some random examples:

```
throw new Mage_Core_Exception('Unable to find writable var_dir');
throw new Mage_Core_Exception(
    Mage::helper('sales')->__('Last status can\'t be unassigned from state.')
);
throw new Mage_Core_Exception(
    $this->__('Some of the processed products have no SKU value defined. Please fill it prior to performing operations on these products.')
);
```

also `Mage::throwException` uses the same class:

```
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cannot get order instance'));
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attribute "%s" is required.', $category->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getFrontend()->getLabel()));
```

There are 2 catch statements

- one for `Mage_Core_Exception` because the user should see the exception message. This should be considered more as "errors in usage of the app" than exceptions
- one for `Exception` (every other exception) where the user sees a a general message like "You cannot do that". Usually when the exception is thrown in cases like you mentioned (table missing, connection errors) the message is logged in `var/log` and not printed in the application.

I think this is a nice way of separating exception types.
But keep in mind 2 things.
Never show the result of `$e->getMessage` when $e is instance of `Exception`, and never throw a `Mage_Core_Exception` whit sensitive data in the message.
If you follow these rules you should be safe.